# Problem in picture overlapping when I convert HTML page to PDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I want to overlap pictures, but it is not working and I need some help.

Here's the link to the page I'd like to convert:
http://9m9.com/innovative/sample/two.html

I want to convert this page to a PDF. You can see the small image overlapping the bigger one.

This is the page where you can click on a link that will convert the page to PDF.
http://citysoftsolutions.com/eclients/virtualtour/view_property_images.php?pid=9&uid=67

As you can see the image is placed behind the big image.
I'm using this converter script: http://mpdf.bpm1.com/

Answer (score 0):

When I printed it using PrimoPDF driver it came out just fine. Last image was easily laid over. So there must be a bug with the script you're using.

What do I suggest?

1. If you'd like to convert your pages to PDFs "on the fly" I suggest you either

   - contact script creator and inform them of a bug in the script
   - use a different script (I'd check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/391005/75642) that can help you)
2. If you'd like to just provide PDFs of your page I suggest you install a PDF printer driver (like PrimoPDF that I'm using) and print those pages yourself and use those.

> I'm not working for *Nitro PDF Software* company nor am I related to them in any way. So this is not me advertising their products/services.

### On a sidenote

Something's telling me that what you'd actually like to do is to create a PDF flyer/promo material or something. If that's actually what you're after I suggest you do that using some software that's meant for such a job. Microsoft Office Word will do, but you'll better off using some other. If it's a one page leaflet you could use Adobe Illustrator or CorelDraw. But if it's going to be an actual multipage document use something like Word or Adobe InDesign.

Word is probably something you can easily master. So go with that one.